# jQuery Form Plugin onComplete dom event

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm using this plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload and it is working except on complete I can't get the following action to get the img src and apply it to another dom element.  I tried adding .delay() but that really didn't do anything at all.

```
$('.submit').bind('click', function(e) {

    $("#fileupload").ajaxForm({
            target: '#status'
    }).submit();


$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
             var mysrc = $("#status").find('img').attr("src");
             $(".empty:first").removeClass("empty").removeClass("ui-state-default").addClass("ui-state").append('<img src="'+mysrc+'" width="45" height="60" class="expand"/>');
         });     

});
```

Comment: From the doc of the plugin, there is no complete action.

Comment: I found one on this page.. http://malsup.com/jquery/form/progress.html

Comment: You're right, didn't see that note : Note: Aside from the options listed below, you can also pass any of the standard $.ajax options to ajaxForm and ajaxSubmit.

Comment: Can you put your HTML, maybe your error is there.

Comment: I updated my code to have ajaxComplete.

Comment: Is there a way to have ajaxComplete only fire once.

Comment: Not sure it's the best approach, if complete work in the plugin, you should use it. As for you "fire only once", just add a condition on a boolean var and change the value of the var after the first call.